# how to trigger jquery custom function when drag event is on google map

Tags: jquery

I'm new to jquery. I'm working on a google map drage event, I have a requirement that if a user is dragging googlemaps some UI element should be hidden.

If the drag event is not in between 5 sec, the hidden UI element should be
displayed again. My drag event looks like:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dragend', custom() 
{ alert('marker dragged'); } );
```

If google map is dragged then it should call below function

```
function custom(){ $("#p").hide() ;}

// if drag event is not triggered in between 5 sec it should call below
function showUIelement() { $("#p").show();}
```

Can anybody please tell me what logic should I should write.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'drag', function() { hideUI(5); } );
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dragend', function() { showUI(.4); } );
```

That was for your map, but you need the function:

```
var hideUI = function(hiddenTime) {  
hiddenTime = (hiddenTime * 1000);
$( "#p" ).fadeOut(hiddenTime / 8).delay(hiddenTime).fadeIn(hiddenTime / 8);
    return true;
}   

var showUI = function(animationTime) {  
animationTime= (animationTime* 1000);
$( "#p" ).fadeIn(animationTime);
    return true;
}
```

PS. remember scope (the map has to be able to access those functions!)

Comment: thanks....i got about hideUI function. it will hide function and will fadeIn after hiddenTime in that case i thing i dont need show UI function pl correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: as i tested this function on click event instead of drag for testing purpose..my requirement is like when i click in between 5 sec  <5 sec it should persist element as hide,( delay should  be added on each click )if there is no click in betw 5 sec then it should display element,    but in above case even i click multiple  time in betw < 5 sec element has been displaying.. here i tried as below code
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("#div1").hide().delay("10000").show("1");
   });
});
<button>Click bt</button><div id="div1" </div>

Comment: Hi, look at my proof of concept with modified code and timer:
http://jsfiddle.net/Olavxxx/w5bsrftc/

Please accept my answer if its worth something to you :-)

Comment: Thanks  exactly as per my requirement  :)

Comment: Glad to be of help, but please accept my answer :) (Since it's resolved)